# why is ssh using cached dns record when dig reports updated version of cname record?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

I have a Jenkins pipeline that will start my AWS Ubuntu EC2 instances.  This Jenkins pipeline will also update a CNAME record I have for my EC2 instances in route53.

Sometimes there is a long delay in my ability to ssh to the instance via the CNAME.  I figured it might be a cache issue, but if I execute `dig the-cname.example.com` I see the updated versions of the DNS records.  Also I have no problem ssh'ing to the new IP and the value of the DNS `A` record that AWS gave my instance.

Is my ssh client using a cached version of the CNAME?

Comment: DNS entries have `TTL` or `Time To Live` which gives an upper bound of time during which the record is considered fresh and shouldn't trigger a new query by client. It seems in your case you might need to lower those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dig` performs an actual DNS query, while `ssh` will simply ask your system (most likely through `gethostbyname`) to resolve a name.

`dig` will ask an actual DNS server while `ssh` will ask the local service in charge of DNS (nowadays, most likely systemd-resolve) which will cache results.

If using systemd, you can clear the cash using `systemd-resolve flush-caches`.

Comment: doh! I forgot to mention that my ssh client is executed from a mac laptop.  I'm sure there is a equivalent command.

Comment: on a mac I can do `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponde`